# Safe reinterpret_cast with sockaddr?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, type-safety, reinterpret-cast

Assume I'm doing some socket programming:

```
struct sockaddr_in sa;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(sa.sin_addr));
auto *resa = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&sa);
bind(sfd, resa, sizeof(sa));
```

Now the question is: we do `reinterpret_cast` (or C-style `(struct sockaddr *)` cast like in tutorials or man) yet the standard does not guarantee that to work, right? On the other hand there does not seem to be a way to do that differently, `bind()` requires `struct sockaddr*` (and it has to access the underlying struct to determine what it received).

So is it safe to do `reinterpret_cast` between different types in this case? If yes then why?

Comment: Hmm, the `sockaddr` structs are designed in an opaque manner. IMO it's OK.

Comment: Yes, it's safe; reinterpret_cast is pretty much the same thing as a C-style cast (except safer because it complains about certain things you might want to know about).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What does it mean that they are designed in this way? How can we design different types to work with `reinterpret_cast`? Is there a specific part of the standard saying something like "if structs/classes X and Y begin with same fields then I can cast one to another and use common fields safely"?

Comment: Strictly undefined behaviour, probably will work, memcpy is the only around this issue.

Comment: @RichardCritten Is it safe to memcpy to a different type?

Comment: @freakish - was just thinking about that .... not sure and if it's not then how to solve the issue in the post. Just found _"Where strict aliasing prohibits examining the same memory as values of two different types, std::memcpy may be used to convert the values."_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy

Comment: must be `reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&sa);` not `reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(sa);` you forget `&` or this is typo ? and use `bind(sfd, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&sa), sizeof(sa));` absolute safe and correct

Comment: @RbMm Yeah, that was a typo.

Comment: @RichardCritten "_Strictly undefined behaviour_" why?

Comment: @curiousguy The full list of valid casts is here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast . Note that casting between pointers to different types is not in the list.  That said, there is so much code out there that does this for networking that disallowing compiler extensions for this sort of thing would probably be a bad idea.

Comment: @RichardCritten Your reference is inexact. "_Unlike static_cast, but like const_cast, the reinterpret_cast expression does not compile to any CPU instructions._" is mostly true, but not always true. Some casts require actual code. Never mind.

Comment: @RichardCritten "_Note that casting between pointers to different types is not in the list_" Are you really claiming what you just claimed? That's a grotesque claim. You are saying that you can't turn an `int*` into `char*` a with `reinterpret_cast`. It's so preposterous I won't bother refuting it.

Comment: @curiousguy The standard explicitely allows `reinterpret_cast` to `char*`: `AliasedType is char, unsigned char, or std::byte: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.`, see "type aliasing" in the link. It's a special case. Anyway I don't think that the case I'm talking about falls into any category mentioned in the article about reinterpret_cast. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @curiousguy was just saying you need to read the entire article before making any claims.  The cast(s) you mention are explicitly listed as valid exceptions.  The comments section of SO is no good for long articles which is why I summarised and linked the original to provide full and complete information.

Comment: @freakish "_The standard explicitely allows reinterpret_cast to char*_" Yes but not relevant. Your claim was "_Note that casting between pointers to different types is not in the list_" Casting between pointers to different types is allowed: "Any pointer to object of type T1 can be converted to pointer to object of another type cv T2. This is exactly equivalent to `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression))`"

Comment: @curiousguy First of all that wasn't my claim. Anyway, you are nitpicking now. Conversions are allowed but the value is unspecified (unlike cast to `char*`). And accessing the structure is UB (unlike cast to `char*`). Thus you can't achieve safely what I am talking about. Unless I'm wrong. Let's stick to the context of the question and not drift away.

Comment: Why do you think that reinterpret_cast is not safe in this case? The C++ code you written doesn't read/write from/to `resa`, so it should be safe (yes, `bind` will read from `resa`, but it is a presumable C lib, C++ rules doesn't apply).

Comment: @geza sure, C++ rules don't apply but I have no choice but to use bind (somewhere under the hood) for networking. So it would be great to have some guarantee that it won't randomly fail. Not that I think it's a big issue.

Comment: I don't think that it will ever fail, if `bind` is compiled to proper object code. I mean, if `bind` is compiled as just lto, it could fail in theory. But I still don't understand: you `reinterpret_cast` (which is fine), then you give the resulting pointer to `bind`. `bind` can be implemented in any language, so it should work no matter how you call it. The only requirement is that the pointer should point to properly formatted bytes, which is true in your case. It would be ridiculous if `bind` cannot be called from C++ code.

Comment: @geza it may fail because reinterpret_cast is not guaranteed to preserve structure that bind requires. In theory it can point to anything or it can do something to the underlying memory.

Comment: Hmm, I may not follow you :) reinterpret_cast is just a cast, it doesn't do anything to the underlying memory. What do you mean by "preserve structure"? What structure? `sa`? As I understand, `resa` should point exactly to the same byte as `&sa` points.

Comment: @geza that's the whole point: the standard doesn't guarantee that. This is expected but not guaranteed in case of unrelated (by inheritance or some special cases) types.

Comment: Are you sure? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast: "10) Otherwise the pointer value is unchanged."

Comment: @geza I'm not sure how to interpret this. But have a look at reinterpret_cast notes (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast ). Accessing members of unrelated cast is explicitely stated as ub. Which again: these are C++ rules, not C. Which is again confusing. But it seems that C++ is at least allowed to do something to the structure such that accessing it may fail.

Comment: Yes, it is confusing for me too. Maybe it's worth a SO question :) Anyways, I don't think that we need to consider accessing. `bind` does the access, which is not covered by the C++ standard.

Comment: You don't have to worry about UB caused by accessing or modifying members through pointer `resa`, since you aren't accessing or modifying any members through that pointer. [\[expr.reinterpret.cast\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#3) has me wondering, though: *"Note: The mapping performed by `reinterpret_­cast` might, or might not, produce a representation different from the original value. — end note"*. That indeed implies, that the object representation of the pointer *can* change. I'm at a loss, what implications that has, but it makes me feel uncomfortable about the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to support many kinds of pointer manipulation is regarded by the Standard as a Quality of Implementation issue.  The Standard does not mandate that all implementations be suitable for low-level or systems programming, but quality implementations suitable for such purpose on e.g. Unix should support the kinds of semantics typically used by systems code on such platform.  An implementation could be incapable of handling code that treats shared parts of structures in type-agnostic fashion and yet still be a high-quality implementation *for some specialized purposes that don't involve any low-level or systems programming*.  On the other hand, a quality implementation suitable for low-level programming should have no trouble handling such code.  Any implementation that can't handle such code should be viewed as being a low-quality implementation and/or unsuitable for low-level programming, and a low-level program's inability to work with such implementations is not a defect.

Answer (score 4):

> So is it safe to do `reinterpret_cast` between different types in this case?

No, not really. You use a pointer to a `sockaddr` in order to point to an object of type `sockaddr_in`. These are unrelated types and so it implies something that isn't true: two unrelated objects are pointed to, but only one object is allocated.

If you work on the most constrained of systems then yes, you might be happy with this and as @supercat says, your implementor might have your back. But your code will not be portable.

> there does not seem to be a way to do that differently

The prescribed solution is to allocate memory for both objects and to use [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to make them equal:

```cpp
sockaddr sa2;
std::memcpy(&sa2, &sa, sizeof(sa));
bind(sfd, &sa2, sizeof(sa));
```

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

> Where strict aliasing prohibits examining the same memory as values of two different types, `std::memcpy` may be used to convert the values.

It is important that the two objects (`sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr`) are the same size. You can assert that this is the case:

```cpp
static_assert(sizeof(sa2) == sizeof(sa));
```

The call to `std::memcpy` is not always free but often it is. ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/KnGaMh39q))

Comment: Jason Turner explains this pretty nicely in [C++ Weekly - Ep 185](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L06nbZXD2D0).

Comment: Unfortunately, this memcpy()-based approach "cuts against the grain" of the BSD sockets API. It happens to work for the specific type sockaddr_in (an IPv4 address) mentioned in the question's example code. But this approach will cause a buffer overflow if you use it on type sockaddr_in6 (an IPv6 address). Because struct sockaddr_in6 happens to be larger than struct sockaddr.

(Admittedly, the BSD sockets API design might be a bit quirky/old. But that API is a fact of life, and we'll have to use C++ in a way that "cuts with the grain" of the API.)

Comment: It's unfortunate that in other circumstances the same API could encourage code with non-portable behaviour. The above solution is not a licence to cause a buffer overrun under those circumstances. I've updated the answer with a `static_assert` which prevents this. Thanks.

Comment: True, it's an unfortunate mismatch of design philosophies. In the BSD sockets API's defense, "it was here first": it goes all the way back to the early 1980ies. The era where it was not abnormal to use C as a portable assembler. Long before the C/C++ strict aliasing rules became an issue. So, it's up to the C++ world to support this preexisting pointer-cast-oriented use case. You rightfully note that the C++ standard does not formally support it. But as noted by @supercat, most practical C++ implementations must guarantee that `reinterpret_cast<>()` behaves like C compilers from the 1980ies.

Comment: (Side note: I won't defend the BSD sockets API on other aspects; it does some other things that *were* dirty even back in its day. For example, it assumes that the bit encoding of a positive number in a `signed short` is identical to the encoding in a `unsigned short`. That's the "All the world's a VAX" mindset, which is warned against by the Ten Commandments for C Programmers. And what really grinds my gears: there was no pressing reason to have that unportable mismash of integer types.)

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the top answer, I would say that `bind` CAN and MUST be written in a way such that `reinterpret_cast` is safe to use here. For instance, `bind` could be implemented as:

```
int bind(SOCKET s, const sockaddr* addr, int addrlen) {
    std::uint16_t address_family;
    std::memcpy(&address_family, addr, sizeof(address_family));
    if (address_family == AF_INET) {
        const sockaddr_in* sin = reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr_in*>(addr);
        // Accessing sin->sin_addr is safe here
        ...
    } else if (address_family == AF_INET6) {
        const sockaddr_in6* sin6 = reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr_in6*>(addr);
        ...
    }
}
```

The key point is that the `reinterpret_cast` itself is not UB, it's trying to access the data that's UB (see [Type Aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)):

> Whenever an attempt is made to **read or modify** the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined[...]

In the code above, we never try to read the contents of `addr` through a pointer of type `sockaddr*`. We examine the value representation (raw bytes) to get the address family, which tells us the exact type of struct to use. Then we can safely cast back to the original type. Casting to a pointer of a different type then back to the original type is allowed by the standard.

Taking it one step further, I would say that with `sockaddr_in6` the implementation must handle `reinterpret_cast` correctly. Since `sizeof(sockaddr_in6) > sizeof(sockaddr)`, the `memcpy` trick no longer works. The API is specifically asking for a pointer to an object of the wrong type, so the onus is on the API implementers to use the pointer correctly.

Comment: That's actually a very good point.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that casting to `struct sockaddr*` is seen in example code and that you are passing it off to a API function (for a well-documented and well-tested library), it is only unsafe if you violate the preconditions of the function.

Casting is necessary because there are different types of `sockaddr` (like `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_un`) and only one type of `bind` function.

The C++ compiler will choose `reinterpret_cast` when doing a C-style cast anyway, but it is preferable to be more explicit for readability.

Comment: The problem is that socket api is C api. And so all tutorials are C tutorials. Perhaps these kind of casts are safe in C, I don't know about that. But it definitely is not guaranteed to work under C++. I know that in practice this works. On the other hand in practice I've never used funky platforms. So perhaps on some platform it will fail? If not then why? So as you can see your answer doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @freakish The answer is correct. C++ `reinterpret_cast` does merely nothing beyond a plain C-style cast (except the `const` correctness maybe).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Fair enough, then what you said is that this is not safe under C as well, right?

Comment: @freakish _Safety_ is relative here. That's why the basic structure has the discriminator type field. Well, that's how polymorphism is done in C.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm very skeptic about that. On one hand, you are right - this is C style polymorphism. On the other hand, this kind of polymorphism is clearly UB in C++ standard (more precisely: accessing structure after reinterpret_cast is UB). Again, I do not know the C standard. Also I'm not really interested in C, so lets focus on C++. What I'm actually interested in is some quote from C++ standard that justifies this. Or perhaps a simple "yeah, this is UB but we do that anyway". This also brings another question: why would C++ standard state that this is UB if everyone does this anyway?

Comment: @freakish Well, UB just means that it's beyond the scope of the C++ standard. You are using a C API. Within that API it's well defined what is necessary to do. Given the fact that `reinterpret_cast` does the same as a C-style cast, and you can rely that the structs are well designed (regarding alignment and aliasing) it's just fine to do so, yes. I've done a lot of network programming BTW, and be assured it worked well on all systems and compilers I met. If you want a C++ abstraction level use something like e.g. `boost::asio`.

Comment: This answer does not address the issue. If you invoke UB the statement "it is only unsafe if you violate the preconditions of the function" is wrong. This answer does not tell us if UB is invoked or not.

Answer (score -2):

yes,this is absolute safe and correct.

> Winsock functions using **sockaddr** are not strictly interpreted to be
>   pointers to a sockaddr structure. The structure is interpreted
>   differently in the context of different address families. The only
>   requirements are that the first **u_short** is the address family and the
>   total size of the memory buffer in bytes is namelen.

so really you need pass **pointer** to some location which begin from `u_short sin_family;` . the [sockaddr_in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496(v=vs.85).aspx) conform this condition. `reinterpret_cast` not change your pointer to `sockaddr_in sa;` and not produce any binary code: `reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sa);` or `(sockaddr*)&sa` is the same as `&sa`. in other words binary **pointer** `&sa == reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sa)`

so you can and must use

```
 bind(sfd, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sa), sizeof(sa));
```

*use `auto *resa` here senseless, for what ?*

alternatively for example we can use next code:

```
union {
    sockaddr sa;
    sockaddr_in sa_in;
};

sa_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa_in.sin_port = *;
sa_in.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = *;
bind(0, &sa, sizeof(sa_in));
```

and main - try put yourself on place who wrote `bind` function. how it must work with `sockaddr` ? obviously it first look to it `sa_family` and then based on it `sa_family` value `reinterpret_cast` it to more specific struct

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178768/discussion-on-answer-by-rbmm-safe-reinterpret-cast-with-sockaddr).